# Wrong total ram ( 8 GB installed, 4 appears and used in total )

Tags: memory, performance, motherboard, bios

I have this motherboard: GA-X38-DQ6 which can hold up to 8 GB of Ram.

When I got this computer it had 4 memory sticks, 1 GB each, and everything was fine. Now, I have two sticks, 4 GB memory each: DDR2 8GB RAM KIT (2x4GB) PC2-6400 800 Mhz 240pin For AMD CPU Chipset. 
Using x64 Windows 7 Operating System.
The problem: When I installed them I can see in dxdiag that I have 8 gb of memory but in task manager the total is 4.

Steps I did to define the problem: At first I thought that 1 of the ram sticks was not working, so I took them out one at a time to check if they were malfunctioning. And I noticed the following thing: Both of the rams were appeared as half in the task manager.

So I believe there must be a bios setting that is wrong or something with the ram sticks. I even tried to boost the voltage for rams  ( from 1.2 normal I made it 1.8 ). I read many similar problems here here, but I did not come to any conclusions so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: It looks like you are using a 64-bit operating system per your link:  prntscr.com/773obb

Comment: When using 2 modules, be sure to install them in the first and third slots, [see page 17 of this pdf](http://download1.gigabyte.us/Files/Manual/motherboard_manual_ga-x38-dq6_c.pdf)

Comment: @Neo: Why did you delete the Task Manager screenshot? Did you edit it out by mistake?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers but i have them in the first and in the third slots nothing changed... I read some people with similar problems talking about voltage in ram. I ran in 1.25 normal and i have placed + 45. But i am afraid to place more. I have read some people say that i should do it 2.1. Anyone knows about it?

Comment: Right click on your Desktop, click Screen Resolution, then Advanced Settings.  Whatever is in Shared System Memory (i.e. System RAM) is unavailable for use other than graphics.

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard chipset supports only 2 GB modules. 4 GB modules are not supported. Please refer the specifications [here](http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2665#sp)

4 x 1.8V DDR2 DIMM sockets supporting up to 8 GB of system memory